# Find non-duplicate rows in table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
|| some_id || value_A || value_B ||  timestamp ||
-------------------------------------------------
||       3 ||    1000 ||       1 || 1362979652 ||
||       3 ||    1001 ||       2 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1002 ||       2 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1003 ||       3 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1004 ||       3 || 1362979652 ||
||       3 ||    1000 ||       1 || 1362980605 ||
||       3 ||    1001 ||       1 || 1362980605 || <-- value_b is different here
||       4 ||    1002 ||       2 || 1362980605 ||
||       4 ||    1003 ||       3 || 1362980605 ||
||       4 ||    1004 ||       2 || 1362980605 || <-- value_b is different here
```

The table consists of a set of data, and then a nearly identical set of data is inserted (with different timestamps). The data is not exactly the same, as the `value_B` is different in some rows, as you can see above.

What I need to do is delete all duplicate rows, and as well as replace the older similar rows with the new ones (the new rows have the newer timestamp).

I have experimented with several different inner join approaches, but I'm having a hard time. I think it's a two part thing. First, I need to simply get rid of the duplicates:

```
|| some_id || value_A || value_B ||  timestamp ||
-------------------------------------------------
||       3 ||    1000 ||       1 || 1362979652 ||
||       3 ||    1001 ||       2 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1002 ||       2 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1003 ||       3 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1004 ||       3 || 1362979652 ||
||       3 ||    1000 ||       1 || 1362980605 || <-- will be deleted
||       3 ||    1001 ||       1 || 1362980605 ||
||       4 ||    1002 ||       2 || 1362980605 || <-- will be deleted
||       4 ||    1003 ||       3 || 1362980605 || <-- will be deleted
||       4 ||    1004 ||       2 || 1362980605 ||
```

Next, I need to delete of any of the OLDER rows if there is a new row left over with the same `some_id` and same `value_A` value.

```
|| some_id || value_A || value_B ||  timestamp ||
-------------------------------------------------
||       3 ||    1000 ||       1 || 1362979652 ||
||       3 ||    1001 ||       2 || 1362979652 || <-- will be deleted
||       4 ||    1002 ||       2 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1003 ||       3 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1004 ||       3 || 1362979652 || <-- will be deleted
||       3 ||    1001 ||       1 || 1362980605 ||
||       4 ||    1004 ||       2 || 1362980605 ||
```

So after processing, the above resulting table would look like this:

```
|| some_id || value_A || value_B ||  timestamp ||
-------------------------------------------------
||       3 ||    1000 ||       1 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1002 ||       2 || 1362979652 ||
||       4 ||    1003 ||       3 || 1362979652 ||
||       3 ||    1001 ||       1 || 1362980605 ||
||       4 ||    1004 ||       2 || 1362980605 ||
```

I'm looking for an efficient solution, because in reality, the table I'm working with has several thousand rows of data. So efficiency is key.

Comment: please check you desired result. i find it incorrect. why can't you say delete the all the previous and keep the latest ones? `:)`

Comment: Because I want to maintain the timestamps of the old, unchanged rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is a bit wrong, since 1001 is a duplicate while 1002 is not but you indicate the reverse in your duplicate elimination step. This simple delete join should get you the correct result though;

```
DELETE a 
FROM MyTable a
JOIN MyTable b
  ON a.value_A=b.value_A
 AND a.some_id = b.some_id
 AND (a.`timestamp` < b.`timestamp` AND a.value_B <> b.value_B OR
      a.`timestamp` > b.`timestamp` AND a.value_B =  b.value_B)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eb64/2).

Of course, never run destructive SQL from random people on the Internet without a backup.

Comment: You are right I had the wrong lines highlighted as duplicates above. I fixed that. I will try your query. Thanks,

Comment: That query worked great, except really slow for my table (with lots of rows). I found a MUCH quicker alternative was to `SELECT *` instead of `DELETE a` and then reverse the final two conditionals so that I select the rows I want to keep instead of the ones I want to delete. I feed this into a new empty table (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`) and then swap the table names, and drop the old table. Much faster. Thanks for the query! It was pretty simple once I saw it.